# How to share the progressbar's progress in two different activities

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-asynctask

- In an activity A I download several files from the server to my device.
- A progressBar shows the progress of the current download.
- I can do multiple downloads at once and I want an activity B shows a list of all my downloads with progressBar for each download.

-The problem is that I do not really know how to share the progress of each download to activity B when I start it via a menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up a downloading `Service` instead of just using an `AsyncTask` to fetch your files.  Then, any `Activity` that's interested in the progress of said downloads can bind the `Service` and register a listener for progress updates which are then reflected in whatever UI is appropriate to the respective `Activity`s.

Comment: Thank you very much, your solution seems correct, I'll try to do it that way!

Answer (score 1):

I am doing something similar and have found success using local broadcasts. I have all the upload logic contained in a Service, which in turn uses an Async task, and when I need to update progress I send out the broadcast. In onResume of my activities I register to receive the notifications and onPause I unregister. That way the current activity can update.

Answer (score 0):

1)Declare Progress Bar inside Application Object(A class that extends Application Supper              class). Now Progress bar is accessible throughout the Application.

2)Update Progress Bar in Activity A.

3)Get Instence of ProgressBar in Activity B by calling getApplication();

Comment: Thank you, but I have several ProgressBars instead of one and I want to make multiple downloads in parrallel.